# Appears error com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Can't convert object of type java.lang.String to type

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Error I want to send again the object and my code wants to convert it to `String`, please help, The error is:

> com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Can't convert object of type java.lang.String to type DetailRestaurant

```
public class UploadImage extends AppCompatActivity {

FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
DatabaseReference myRef;
private EditText nameImageR;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_upload_image);

    myRef = database.getReference("").child("users");
    nameImageR = findViewById(R.id.nameImageR);

    Button map = findViewById(R.id.buttonUpload);
    map.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override

        public void onClick(View view) {
            writeNewImage();
            Intent Client= new Intent(UploadImage.this, MainRestaurantActivity.class);
            startActivity(Client);
            finish();
        }
    });
}
private void writeNewImage() {
    myRef = database.getReference("users").child("restaurant").child(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid());
    ValueEventListener valueEventListener = myRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for (DataSnapshot areaSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                DetailRestaurant value1 = areaSnapshot.getValue(DetailRestaurant.class);
                value1.setImageRestaurant(nameImageR.getText().toString());
                if (value1.getUid().equals(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid())) {
                    String userIDR = value1.getUid();
                    myRef = database.getReference("");
                    myRef.child("users").child("restaurant").child(userIDR).setValue(value1);
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
            Log.d("Eror", "Something happened");
        }
    });
}
}

public class DetailRestaurant implements Serializable {

private String name;
private String uid;
private String ImageRestaurant;
private HashMap<String, DetailPlate> plates;

public DetailRestaurant(){
    this.plates = new HashMap<String, DetailPlate>();
}

public DetailRestaurant(String ImageRestaurant){
    this();
    this.ImageRestaurant = ImageRestaurant;
}

public DetailRestaurant(String name, String uid) {
    this();
    this.name = name;
    this.uid = uid;
}

public DetailRestaurant(String name, String uid, String ImageRestaurant, HashMap<String, DetailPlate> plates) {
    this.name = name;
    this.uid=uid;
    this.ImageRestaurant = ImageRestaurant;
    this.plates = plates;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}
public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
public String getUid() {
    return uid;
}
public void setUid(String uid) {
    this.uid = uid;
}
public String getImageRestaurant() {
    return ImageRestaurant;
}
public void setImageRestaurant(String imageRestaurant) {
    ImageRestaurant = imageRestaurant;
}
public void setPlates(HashMap<String, DetailPlate> plates) {
    this.plates = plates;
}
public HashMap<String, DetailPlate> getPlates(){ return plates; }
public ArrayList<DetailPlate> getPlatesList() {
    ArrayList<DetailPlate> plates = new ArrayList<DetailPlate>();
    for (DetailPlate p : this.plates.values()){
        plates.add(p);
    }
    return plates;

}
@Override
public String toString() {
    return this.getName();
}

}
```

> E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                     Process: com.example.fernandalopezcardenas.uneatfinal, PID: 9713
>                     com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Can't convert object of type java.lang.String to type com.example.fernandalopezcardenas.uneatfinal.Detail.DetailRestaurant
>                         at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbtg.zze(Unknown Source)
>                         at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbtg.zzb(Unknown Source)
>                         at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbtg.zza(Unknown Source)
>                         at com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot.getValue(Unknown Source)
>                         at com.example.fernandalopezcardenas.uneatfinal.Restaurant.UploadImage$2.onDataChange(UploadImage.java:56)
>                         at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbpx.zza(Unknown Source)
>                         at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbqx.zzZT(Unknown Source)
>                         at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbra$1.run(Unknown Source)
>                         at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:746)
>                         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
>                         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5459)
>                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:728)
>                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)

Comment: Show the line where the error occurs it must be mentioned in android studio and say which line?

Comment: DetailRestaurant value1 = areaSnapshot.getValue(DetailRestaurant.class); is in the 56 of the class UploadImage

Comment: Please add you database structure.

Answer (score 0):

Had same problem,You need to do another inner iteration over first datasnapshot. Try like this..

```
 for (DataSnapshot areaSnapshotOne : dataSnapshot.getChildren())
                {
                    for (DataSnapshot areaSnapshotTwo : areaSnapshotOne.getChildren())
                    {
         DetailRestaurant value1 = areaSnapshotTwo.getValue(DetailRestaurant.class);
Log.d("details",value1.toString());

                          /*your rest code here*/
                    }
                }
```

Comment: java.lang.NullPointerException: Can't pass null for argument 'pathString' in child() this error appears I get rid of this line if (value1.getUid().equals(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid()))

Comment: @Jessica Sohr did this error resolved `Can't convert object of type java.lang.String to type DetailRestaurant `

Comment: put log and see if value1 has `String uid` value in it. check my updated answer.

Comment: for (DataSnapshot areaSnapshotOne : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    Log.d("details1", areaSnapshotOne.toString());
                    for (DataSnapshot areaSnapshotTwo : areaSnapshotOne.getChildren()) {
                        DetailRestaurant value1 = areaSnapshotTwo.getValue(DetailRestaurant.class);
                        Log.d("details",value1.toString());

Comment: D/details1: DataSnapshot { key = name, value = Juvie Jus }
D/details1: DataSnapshot { key = plates, value = {-KzmCDcYsoXpayxEmLpL={uidrestaurant=taoGAfndxbcuooJuN00SuJ31Xry2, name=waffles, price=45, uidrequest=-KzmCDcYsoXpayxEmLpL, ingredients={0=honey, 1= strawberries, 2= butter}, imagePlate=https://assets.epicurious.com/photos/54b40ef4d5e8c3e1070b0181/master/pass/394693_waffles_1x1.jpg}, -KzmCXX_7Qg6_wNiSNEY={uidrestaurant=taoGAfndxbcuooJuN00SuJ31Xry2, name=Taco, price=30, uidrequest=-KzmCXX_7Qg6_wNiSNEY, ingredients={0=onion, 1= cilantro, 2= pineapple}} }
D/details: waffles

Comment: I want to set an string and send it back to firebase

Comment: Remember you need to set values to your pojo class fields and then add it to firebase database.